# Javascript interview question (mul functions)

Tags: javascript, indexing

Any idea how this works this way?

```js
function mul(x) {
    return function(y) {
 return [x*y, function(z) {
     return x*y + z;
 }];
    }
}

console.log(mul(2)(3)[0]);
console.log(mul(2)(3)[1](4));
```

I am not sure how giving the index in the mul function works

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question. Why would it not work that way? The second level of the function returns an array, array elements can be accessed by index. There's nothing more to it than that.

Comment: Which way do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, a function can be a return value from another function.
In this case `mul` is returning a function which in case returns an array. The first element in the array is x*y and the second element is a function.

```js
mul(2); // Returns a function which can take one argument
mul(2)(3) // Invoking the function returned from mul using 3 as argument, this will return the array

mul(2)(3)[0]; // Accessing the first element of the array - 6
mul(2)(3)[1](4); /** With mul(2)(3)[1] we are accessing the second element of the array, 
                  since it is a function taking one argument we can pass 4 as argument to it
                 **/
```

Answer (score 0):

Robby is correct. To expand on his explanation... The first console.log;

```
console.log(mul(2)(3)[0]);
```

is returning the index 0 of the array that was returned after the first two functions were called... x*y, which is 2*3 = 6. The second console.log;

```
console.log(mul(2)(3)[1](4));
```

is returning index 1 at that point, which returns the function that takes z as a parameter... once z is passed to the function it returns x*y + z which is 2*3 + 4 = 10.

Answer (score 0):

it's kinda hard to understand nested functions, but you normally use them when you want to wait for some value.

For example, let's pretend i don't have **z** in this case:

```
function sum(y, z) {
    return y + z;
}
```

So i can clearly use a nested function, so i can wait for z like this:

```
function sum(y) {
    return function(z) {
        return y + z;
    }
}

const temporaryValue = sum(10); // it returns another function;

const result = temporaryValue(5); // here, i have the function result
```

What your code is doing, is basically it! But it's using an array. I'll try to explain it for you.

```
function mul(x){
    return function(y) { // returns another function
        // that returns an array, with another function inside it
        return [x * y, function(z) {
            return x * y + z; // that returns it's result;
        }];
    }
}

const temporaryAgain = mul(2); // returns a function
const nearThere = temporaryAgain(3); // returns an array
const result = nearThere[1](4); // [1] returns a function and (4) returns the result
```

That's exactly what the code you send does!! Hope i helped a little bit.
If not, i highly recommend you to study a bit about [nested functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-nested-functions/).